# How to get highest value from string Split() c#

Tags: c#

so I want to print the oldest persons age (for example person writes: Patrick,50 Steven,25) the code will print: age of the oldest: age

**Obviously this is an exercise I am not trying to hide it**

Here is the base of the code:

```
while (true)
            {
                string input = Console.ReadLine();

                if (input == "")
                {
                    break;
                }

                string[] pieces = input.Split(",");
```

Comment: is there a comma between 50 and Steven? How the input is maintain relationship between person name and age? is pattern like `person1name, person1age, person2name, person2age`?

Comment: Unrelated: `if (input == "")` - maybe prefer `if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(input)`

Comment: Break it into steps. First you need to decide on a data structure to hold your data (probably a `Dictionary<>` of some kind). Then you need to write code to populate the data structure. You might have to convert a string into an `int` and figure out what to do if it doesn't work. Then you need to write code to take the max from the data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var oldestAge = 0;
        var oldestName = "";
    
        while (true)
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            if (input == "")
            {
                break;
            }

            string[] pieces = input.Split(",");


            for (var i = 0; i < pieces.Length; i += 2)
            {
                var name = pieces[i]; 
                var age = int.Parse(pieces[i + 1]);
                if (age > oldestAge)
                {
                    oldestAge = age;
                    oldestName = name;
                }
            }
         
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"{oldestName} {oldestAge}");
    }
```

We're storing the `oldestAge` and `oldestName` values, and we check against each person coming in whether they're older than the `oldestAge` -- setting `oldestAge` and `oldestName` if they are.

An example run of the program would look like:

```
Luke,25,Harry,32
Dan,33,Paul,75

Paul 75
```

Comment: How do you think `input.Split(",")` will work on the given input?  ("Patrick,50 Steven,25" => "Patrick" ;  "50 Steven";   "25" )

Comment: My assumption was that each record would be entered one at a time, I can see that's not how the SO has specified the question.

Comment: The answer has been updated since your comment @Luuk

Comment: @LukeGarrigan "_My assumption was that each record would be entered one at a time_" And that the second comma delimited string will contain an integer. Personally I would have `int.TryParse` instead

Comment: Yeah, I agree @Cleptus. There's a lot of defensive programming I personally would do here, but my goal was to give the simplest solution to get the programmer on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should create a class called `Person`, containing `Name` and `Age` as a property, Like

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; } = 0;

    public Person(string name, string ageStr)
    {
      this.Name = name;
      int.TryParse(ageStr, out this.Age);
    }
}
```

Once you split the string, create a list of `Person` class and add each person details,

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
for(int i = 0; i < pieces.Length; i = i + 2) //look at increment, jumping i by 2
{
    var person = new Person(pieces[i], pieces[i + 1]);
    people.Add(person);
}
```

Now use Linq, [`OrderByDescending()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending?view=net-6.0) & [`First()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=net-6.0) to get first highest record,

```
var eldestPerson = people.OrderByDescending(x => x.Age).First();
```

Now you can print, `Name` as well as `Age` of eldest person

```
Console.WriteLine($"Eldest Person Name: {eldestPerson.Name} Age: {eldestPerson.Age}");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making a quite difficult exercise to start: I would advise you to start working with a list of ages and get the highest one, something like:

```
20, 50, 35, 15, 20
=> the result should be 50.
```

Once you have this right, you can start adding names to your list:

```
Alice, 20, Bjorn, 50, Charlie, 35, Dave, 15, Evelyn, 20
=> First thing to realise is that not all entries are numbers (the question "Is Charlie larger than 35?" makes no sense),
   so you need to find a way to check if the entry is a name or a number.
=> the result should be 50.
```

Now you'll be interested in the person who is actually 50 years old. You might do this by running through your list again, and taking the previous entry.

```
=> the result should be "Bjorn".
```

Then you might start wondering: in order to know the person with the highest age, I'm running through the list twice: once for knowing the highest age and once for knowing whose age this is, and you realise that you'd better keep the index of the highest age you're trying to find, so that you can use that index for retrieving the corresponding name without running through your list again.

Have fun

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the input string is in exactly the same format as you mentioned, you could try the following:

```
string[] pieces = input.Split(',');
var oldestAge = pieces.Select( (piece, i) =>
                                 i > 0 ? int.Parse(piece.Split(' ')[0]) : int.MinValue
                                 ).Max();
Console.WriteLine(oldestAge);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Enumerable.Max](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=net-6.0) from System.Linq to get the highest value from a list.

An example:

```
var ages = new string[4];
ages[0] = "10";
ages[1] = "45";
ages[2] = "55";
ages[3] = "100";

var highest = ages.ToList().Select(a => Convert.ToInt32(a)).Max();
Console.WriteLine(highest); //Prints out 100 to console
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed some exercise in C# too. Here is my solution:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string pattern = @"([0-9]+)|([a-zA-Z]+)";
string input = @"Patrick,50 Steven,25 Dirk,50";
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

Dictionary<string, uint> persons = new Dictionary<string, uint>();

string name = "";
uint age = 0;
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
{
    uint.TryParse(m.Value, out age);
    if (age == 0)
    {
        name = m.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        persons.Add(name, age);
    }
}

uint maxAge = persons.Values.Max();

foreach (var p in persons.Where(x => x.Value == maxAge))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{p.Key} {p.Value}");
}
```

output:

```
Patrick 50
Dirk 50
```

- This is, so far, the only solution which detects multiple persons having the maxAge ?

And, of course, [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/btdekB/1) did help!